# Compare array with object key in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below array ,

```
["aa","bb"]
```

I have below object,

```
{"aa":1,"bb":2,"cc":3}
```

and I need result below,

```
{"cc":3}
```

I need to compare array with object keys, using looping it is possible,but it take more time for large amount data, is there any other fastest way to get my result without using loop, Anyhelp Appreciated...

Comment: Can you share what have you tried?

Comment: So, you want to find properties in the object that are not present in the array?

Comment: probably going to have to implement a function like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference

Comment: Do you want to create a new object, or change the existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid quadratic time complexity you could use a Set and pass that as the `this` argument to the filter. Then recompose an object from those filtered keys with `Object.assign`:

```js
var a = ["aa","bb"];
var b = {"aa":1,"bb":2,"cc":3};

var difference = Object.assign(...Object.keys(b).filter(function(e){
  return !this.has(e);
}, new Set(a)).map(key => ({ [key]: b[key] }) ));

console.log(difference);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with mutating the object, then you can use `delete` to remove the unwanted properties.

```js
const props = ["aa","bb"];
const obj = {"aa": 1,"bb": 2,"cc": 3};

props.forEach(prop => delete obj[prop]);

console.log(obj);
```

Or just loop over the array of property names with `for...of`.

```js
const props = ["aa","bb"];
const obj = {"aa": 1,"bb": 2,"cc": 3};

for (prop of props) delete obj[prop];

console.log(obj);
```

If you don't want to mutate the object, but instead create a new one without he unwanted properties, then you can do a shallow clone first with

```
newObj = {...obj};
```

Comment: @Nina `props` was supposed to be the array, so `for (prop of props)` takes its values one by one. I've clarified that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```js
var a = ["aa","bb"];
var b = {"aa":1,"bb":2,"cc":3};

var result = {};

Object.keys(b).filter(function(e){
  return a.indexOf(e) < 0;
}).forEach(function(e){
  result[e] = b[e];
});


console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can alternatively use `array.reduce` as OP wants an object with missing keys and their values

Comment: This is a bad code. OP has clearly said that it is a BIG object. So looping twice is a bad idea. try `var result = Object.keys(obj).reduce( (p,c)=> (!keys.includes(c) && p[c] = obj[c], p) ,{})`

Comment: @Rajesh, looping a second time with `forEach` is not an issue here. Nesting a call to `includes` (or `indexOf`) will have a much bigger time impact (for larger arrays) than that. It makes the time complexity *O(n²)* instead of *O(n)*. The `forEach` does not increase the time complexity above *O(n)*.

Comment: @trincot even Ivan is using `.indexOf`. All I did was used `.reduce` instead of `.filter + .forEach`. My point was, adding an `if` can remove the need fpr second loop

Comment: Sure, you can remove the need for a second loop, but to call Ivan's code "bad code" just because of the second loop is really not warranted.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the object and check to see if the property doesn't exist in the array:

```js
var a = ["aa","bb"];
var o = {"aa":1,"bb":2,"cc":3};

// Loop through object
for(var prop in o){
  // If property doesn't exist in array...
  if(a.indexOf(prop) === -1){
    console.log(prop + ":" + o[prop]);
  }  
}
```

Comment: I guess using `.hasOwnProperty` would be better

Comment: @Rajesh OP didn't say anything about inherited properties.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through the object and compare the object keys with the array items and return the missing keys as an object.

```js
var a = ["aa","bb"] ;
var o = {"aa":1,"bb":2,"cc":3,'dd':4};

function get(o){
var p = {};
for(var key in o){
 if(a.indexOf(key) == -1){
     p[key] = o[key];
  }
}
return p;
}
var c = get(o);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign()`, `Object.entries()`, `Array.prototype.includes()` to determine if current key in object is an element of array, return object using computed property or false, which does not result in property being assigned to new object

```js
var arr = ["aa","bb"] 

var obj = {"aa":1,"bb":2,"cc":3}

var res =  Object.assign({}
           , ...Object.entries(obj).map(([key, prop]) =>
               !arr.includes(key) && {[key]:prop})
           );

console.log(res);
```